# Insert multiple JSON column in MySQL (using API)

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm trying to store sports data json column using API but I can't get it working properly. Though I can insert the data but it insert only the first column result and keep it duplicating on all the later columns. At default, it shows 50 column upcoming football matches. My problem is only the first line result is duplicating..

Here is the code:

```
//connect to mysql db
$host = "localhost";
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";
$db = "dname";
$conn = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db) or die("ERROR:could not connect to 
    the database!!!");

//read the json file contents
$url = 'http://api.example.com/v1/events/upcoming?token=566645-
    sl1uDzY3tVvv9M&league_id=78&sport_id=1';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));

if ($data === false) {
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    die('error occured during curl exec. Additioanl info: ' .
            var_export($info));
}
curl_close($ch);
$obj = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ($obj['results'] as $res) {
    $league = $res['league']['name'];
    $home = $res['home']['name'];
    $away = $res['away']['name'];
    $time = date("d/m h:i", $res['time']);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO schedule(league, home, away, time)
    VALUES('$league', '$home', '$away', '$time')";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (!$result) {
    die("ERROR :" . mysqli_error());
} else {
    echo "Records has been successfully inserted";
}
//close the connection
mysqli_close($conn);
```

The above code just insert the first json result, and it keeps repeating for the next column (result).. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: INSERT query must be in foreach

Comment: Also you can first print all data to check whether all unique columns are coming. Add echo "<pre>"; print_r($obj['results']); die; before foreach

Answer (score 1):

You are facing the problem because you are executing mysql query outside the `foreach` loop. You have to execute the query inside the loop.

Do something like

```
foreach ($obj['results'] as $res) 
{ 
$league = $res['league']['name']; 
$home = $res['home']['name']; 
$away = $res['away']['name']; 
$time = date("d/m h:i", 
$res['time']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO schedule(league, home, away, time) VALUES('$league', '$home', '$away', '$time')";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
if(!$result) 
{ 
die("ERROR :". mysqli_error()); 
} else 
{
echo "Records has been successfully inserted";
 } //close the connection mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your insert query must be in foreach like below:

```
foreach ($obj['results'] as $res){
    $league = $res['league']['name'];
    $home = $res['home']['name'];
    $away = $res['away']['name'];
    $time = date("d/m h:i", $res['time']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO schedule(league, home, away, time)
    VALUES('$league', '$home', '$away', '$time')";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    if(!$result){
        die("ERROR :". mysqli_error());
    }else{
        echo "Records has been successfully inserted";
    }
}
```

Though the above code can resolve your issue but its better if you start using MySqli **Prepared Queries** to make it more secure.

Follow below link for more details:

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Appreciate for suggestion.. The loop keep repeating as the page refreshes.. Can you point the solution?

Comment: Have you tried with echo "<pre>"; print_r($obj['results']); die; before foreach

Comment: First check what data is coming

Comment: It will surely work if the data is coming in the form of array if you put insert query inside foreach.

Answer (score 0):

Put your insert query in foreach loop. Because your variable replace with new foreach result. Foreach reassign your veriables.

```
foreach ($obj['results'] as $res) {
    $league = $res['league']['name'];
    $home = $res['home']['name'];
    $away = $res['away']['name'];
    $time = date("d/m h:i", $res['time']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO schedule(league, home, away, time)
    VALUES('$league', '$home', '$away', '$time')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (!$result) {
        die("ERROR :" . mysqli_error());
    } else {
        echo "Records has been successfully inserted";
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate for response, but this doesn't stop the loop.. It keeps doubling as the page refreshes.

Comment: Redirected to parent URL or Reassign your json variable as a blank